# Вызов функции при наследовании с++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, полиморфизм, virtual

Всем здравствуйте. Я сейчас изучаю `virtual` функции и у меня возник вопрос. У меня имеется 2 класса:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    void say()
    {
        cout << "I am Parent" << endl;
    }
};
class Child : public Parent
{
    void say() 
    {
        cout << "I am Child" << endl;
    }
};
```

И теперь я сделаю вот так:

```
int main()
{
   Parent* pParent = new Child ();
   pParent->say();
}
```

На вывод получаю:

`I am Parent`

Так вот вопрос: почему вызывается функция класса-родителя, когда по всей логике должна вызываться функция класса-наследника. Неужели компилятор не видит, что через `->` мы вызываем именно метод у класса наследника, объект которого лежит по указателю. Да я знаю, что для решения этой проблемы существует `virtual`. Но для чего вся эта канитель?

Comment: *"Неужели компилятор не видит, что через -> мы вызываем именно метод у класса наследника"* - компилятор видит, что в выражении `pParent->say();` у объекта с типом `Parent` вызывается метод `say`. При чем то же самое произошло бы и в ситуации, если бы метод `say` был виртуальным, только в этом случае вызов метода базового класса привел бы к виртуальной диспетчеризации во время выполнения.

Comment: Точно! Что-то я совсем уже:(

Comment: если бы компилятор работал по принципу "вижу не вижу", то плюсы были бы ещё сложнее. И на работу мы бы ходили с хрустальным шаром.

Comment: @user7860670, погодите-ка, неужели создавая указатель на объект, мы создадим объект, для которого мы сможем вызвать его метод?

Comment: если мы создадим указатель, то объект не создается. А значит вызывать у него ничего не получится. Объект создается через явный или неявный вызов конструктора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для чего канитель? для эффективности, например :) - чтоб не рыться во время работы в таблице виртуальных функций.

- Функция **не** `virtual`? Значит, связывание *статическое*, исходя из типа объекта времени компиляции - `Parent`.
- Функция `virtual`? Значит, связывание *динамическое*, получаем указатель, смотрим по указателю в таблицу виртуальных функций, ищем нужную, вызываем...